# Declare a PIC pin in a variable

Tags: pic, microchip, pins, mplabx, variable

So basically, I want to store a pin of a PIC MCU inside of a variable. eg.

```
int pin = LATB5
```

I also need to pass that pin to a function. If I do it like this, it doesn’t give any errors, but the state of the pin remains the same no matter what. How would I do it properly?

Comment: You need to show us what you're doing with `pin`.

Comment: _Edit your question_ to tell us what language that is.  I expect that it's some PIC-compatible flavor of C, but you need to tell us which one.  Because since PIC's aren't a very good fit _at all_ with the C virtual machine, you either need an inefficient implementation of C (basically forcing the PIC to do extra work to emulate the C virtual machine) or you need a version of C that doesn't conform well at all to standard.

Comment: Generally, you need to look into the MCU definition files to see what LATB5 actually is such as it's variable. Generally it's an alias for the register address for the GPIO port or a bit position or both. And that's what you actually store as a variable. Sometimes it's more complicated because you can only write to the entire register for the GPIO port so if you want to change just the one pin you bit mask the position with the register.

Comment: With the XC8 compiler under MPLAB X, the port pins are bitfields of a struct, so can't really be addressed this way. Every time I've needed to do something like this, I've written wrapper functions that take a value that's mapped to the pin.

Comment: Missing keyword in my previous post: "Generally, you need to look into the MCU definition files to see what LATB5 actually is such as it's variable *type*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using XC8 for a Microchip PIC device. I don't know how you plan to use the variable "pin", but declaring it as an integer will just allocate a place in RAM, where an assignment of "pin = LATB5" will just store the bit number "5". You might try this:

```
#define pin LATBbits.LATB5
```

You can only assign a value of zero or one to a pin, so this will work:

```
pin = 0;  // reset pin low
pin = 1;  // set pin high
```

It is usually more useful to define a pin according to what it does. So if it controls a status LED, do something like this:

```
#define  STATUS_LED  LATBbits.LATB5
#define  ON  1
#define  OFF  0

STATUS_LED = ON;
STATUS_LED = OFF;
```

(edit)
Here is a test program with a function setpin( port, pin, value ) that can do what (I think) you want.

```
/* 
 * File:   setpin.c
 * Author: paul
 * Device: PIC16F9876A
 * Created on October 31, 2022
 */

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = EXTRC     // Oscillator Selection bits (RC oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = ON       // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT enabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define OFF   0
#define ON    1

void    setpin(volatile unsigned char *port, unsigned char pin, int value)
{
    if(value==0)
        *port &= ~(1<<pin);
    else
        *port |= 1<<pin;
}

    void main(void)
  {
        TRISA=0;
        TRISB=0;
        ADCON1bits.PCFG = 0b0111;
        PORTA = 0x3f;
        PORTB = 0;
        setpin( &PORTA, 5, OFF);
        setpin( &PORTA, 2, OFF);
        setpin( &PORTB, 3, ON);
        setpin( &PORTB, 7, ON);
    while(1);
    }
```

Comment: So, i have a function that takes a pin as an argument. myFunc(int pin){                       pin=1;                                          __delay_ms(500);                    pin=0;                                         __delay_ms(500);                     return;                                       }                                                 This is just an oversimplification of the function.

Comment: That will work if you use "#define pin LATBbits.LATB5", or possibly "#define pin LATB5". But you can't declare pin as integer. You probably need the function to be "myFunc(void)".

Comment: Ok, I hoped I would be able to just pass it as an integer. I managed to do it by bitmasking so it works now. Thanks for the help.